# Can't get a lower triangular nxn determinant

Tags: determinant

I'm trying to solve the following nxn determinant:

$
\displaystyle  
\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 &\ldots &1\\ 1 & a_1& 0& \ldots & 0\\ 1 & 0 &a_2 &\ldots &0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & 0& 0 & \ldots & a_n \\ \end{vmatrix}
$

I've tried subtracting the last row from all the others except the first in order to get a lower triangle determinant but I still don't know how to get rid of the 1 on the bottom left corner. Any hints?

Comment: What about subtracting $1/a_i$ times row $i$ from the first row?

Answer (score 2):

The determinant $d$ is unchanged if you replace the first row by
$$
\mathbf{r}_1 \leftarrow 
\mathbf{r}_1 - \frac{1}{a_1} \mathbf{r}_2 - \ldots - \frac{1}{a_N} \mathbf{r}_{N+1}
$$
(if none of the $a$'s are null)

It follows that
$$
d=
\begin{vmatrix}
-\sum a_n^{-1} & 0  & 0  &  & 0\\
1  & a_1 &   &  & \\
1  &   & a_2 &  & \\
\vdots &  &  & \ddots & \\
1  &  &  & & a_N
\end{vmatrix}=
-(\sum a_n^{-1})(\prod a_n)
$$

Comment: +1, but it's not the end of the story. If any $a_i=0$, then make it nonzero and $a_i\to0$. Since the determinant is a polynomial in the matrix elements, it's also continuous. Now, find out the polynomial: the formula you found can be simplified to $-\sigma_{n-1}=-\sum_i\prod_{j\ne i} a_j$. And this one is valid for any $a_i$, zero or nonzero.

Comment: very nice simplification !

Comment: @downmath After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).